# .gitignore all bin folders only in some directory in subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is a portion of my `.gitignore` (which was generated by Visual Studio):

```
[Bb]in/

!src/NWatch_WebUI/buildtools/node_modules/*/[Bb]in/
```

I want to check in all the files in the `node_modules` folder, however, git is flagging any `bin` folder in the node_modules and deeper.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines to `.gitignore`:

```
**/[Bb]in
!src/NWatch_WebUI/buildtools/node_modules/*/[Bb]in
```

Comment: Furthermore perhaps use a double asterisk (`**`) for the bang. Sorry for two post ;)